# Can REST be used instead of URL Rewrite in CF10?

Tags: rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Can the REST support in CF10 be used to replace the use of URL Rewrite / ModRewrite for SEO-friendly URL?  Write a thin layer that defines the GET and POST method, and `<cfinclude>` in the correct page?

Or would it tax the server too much and better leave it to the web server to deal with?

Once in CFML, it'd be much easier to be version controlled and maintained.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Henry
REST is not a replacement for the URL rewriting.

First of all the REST URLs have a format.

http://localhost:8500/rest/App_Name/Rest_Path

"rest" part is mandatory. If you want to change "rest" you can change it in the web.xml (Change the URL Mapping).

App_Name is not mandatory. A server can have a default rest application. For default applications you do not need to specify the AppName. For accessing other (non-default) rest applications, you should specify, the AppName. You can make an application default in the Rest Service registration page in the admin.

Rest_Path identifies the CFC and the function in the CFC that needs to be invoked on the HTTP call.

If these URL format is acceptable, then the URL of these formats can be mapped to a specific function in a CFC. When ever an HTTP call is made to the URL, the corresponding CFFunction will be invoked. By using REST, you are accessing a function in the CFC. It is not possible to access a CFC or a CFM directly in this way. But in the function you can implement whatever you want(Like invoking a CFC, Invoking another CFM etc.).

Does this reply answer your question?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Cool, so it seems it is doable, if I change the "rest" to something else in `web.xml` and no AppName.  Is translating REST URL heavy for CF?  Would it kill CF on search engine crawl?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are saying (and perhaps I do not) you would create a handler that would intercept a request, parse out the variables, then request the appropriate page via REST?  If that's what you have in mind then I'm not sure I follow what you would gain by this. REST (in general) is more of a generic HTTP API for getting at methods - not so much a page / content paradigm (thought I suppose it could be).

If what you are looking for is to use CF as an rewrite SEO URL handler you can do this now. To use an IIS example, you can create a "custom 404" handler - a CFM page - that gets all the requests that are not tied to a specific document. The handler teases out the variables by parsing through the URL, then "includes" the correct cfm Code or page. That sounds a bit like what you want - but it's not really REST.

Perhaps you are thinking of doing some sort of CFHTTP call where you grab the content you need by constructing the query string from the URL. So if someone loads a url like:

blah.com/productid/550

You could write code like so -

```
<cfhttp 
url="http://blah.com/index.cfm?#listfirst(cgi.script_name,'/')#=#listlast(cgi.script_name,'/')#"/>

<cfoutput>#cfhttp.filecontent#</cfoutput>
```

While this would do the trick you would be better off using cfinclude rather than this approach. An approach like the one above would actually generate an additional thread per request - one thread for the browser's request and another for the cfhttp request.

Finally I would suggest politely that URL Rewrite (in apache or IIS) is more efficient and more "conventional" and therefore probably a better choice in general.

Comment: I think what he is asking is if CF10 handles routing of 
REST-like addresses to components in some manner, can that simply be used as the primary way to route requests and outputting html. I don't know the answer to that but I suppose the main factor in the answer is whether it allows for arbitrary output of content, or only XML/JSON like webservice supported by CF in the past.

Comment: I have not tried it, but CF10 introduces REST support that can do regex on URL and maps GET/POST/PUT/DELETE as methods of the CFC.  So I wonder if we can make SEO website with friendly URL using that feature and migrate the responsibility from web server's rewrite module to CF.

Comment: Ah.. I see what you are driving at. I'm a little curious as to why you think this would be better or more manageable than URLrewrite though? Seems like you are replacing a fairly simple device with one crafted by Rube Goldberg :)

Comment: @MarkAKruger For one it'll be web server agnostic?  Also CFML is easier to version control than web server configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Even if one could do this, I'd say it's co-opting the wrong tool to do the wrong job.  URL rewriting is the web server's job, not the CF server's, and the web server will be a hell of a lot better at it than CF will be.  CF's REST interface is for building APIs, not for doing URL rewriting.

If one *was* to want to handle URL rewriting with CF, then using the 404 handler or onMissingTemplate() handler would be a better fit here, would it not?  At least you're using a tool intended for the job (if not the best one).

As for version control... an .htaccess file is just a text file, like a CFML file is.  I've not looked too closely at IIS's rewrite module, but can it not use a text file to configure / maintain its rewrites?  Obviously Apache can, and we use Helicon's ISAPI Rewrite module which uses an mod_rewrite-compatible .htaccess file.

It seems to me like you're trying to make the developer's job easier by using an approach that would penalise the production performance.  "Making the developer's life easier" should never be grounds for compromising the production environment (IMO, obviously).

Comment: The other thing I'd add here, Henry... I didn't think about it until after I pressed "send", is that .htaccess and [however IIS does it] is an industry-accepted and well understood approach (if we don't already know how to do it, it's well documented).  Trying to do it with the CF REST mechanism is going to be "bespoke", so less easy for a third-party to pick up should they need to.  "Don't reinvent the wheel", basically, I guess.